# Lwt_main.run実行中にシグナルを受けたら後処理をして停止したい

Tags: ocaml

```
let rec f _ = ignore (Lwt_unix.sleep 1.0);
              f ()
let _ = Lwt_unix.on_signal 2 (fun _ -> print_endline "sig")
let _ = 
  print_endline "start";
  ignore (Lwt_main.at_exit (fun () -> Lwt.return(print_endline "at_exit")));
  Lwt_main.run (f ())
```

上記のように書いてみましたが、Ctrl-CでSIGINTを送っても割り込めないようです。
きちんと割り込めるやり方か、at_exitと共通化できるようなもっと良い方法があれば教えて下さい。
環境はOCaml4.02.1, lwt2.4.8です。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Lwt_unix.sleep 1` の結果が捨てられ、 `f ()` がすぐ呼ばれています。`sleep` の前に debug print を入れれば一秒待たずに即 `f ()` が呼ばれてしまっているのが判ると思います。

この `f` が `Lwt_main.run (f ())` の引数に出てくる所で無限ループに入ってしまうので、 プログラムを実行しても `Lwt_main.run` には入りません。Lwt エンジンの signal handling などは `run` 内部で行われるので、このままでは(調べていませんが)うまく行くとは思いません。

まず、`Lwt_unix.sleep 1.0` の結果を `bind` (もしくは `lwt () = ... in ...`)で受けなければ、『一秒後に何かする」という動作になりません。

ちょっと試してみましたが、シグナルハンドラ内で `exit 0` すれば `at_exit` は呼ばれるようですので、次のようにするとよいのかなと思います。

```
open Lwt

let rec f () = bind (Lwt_unix.sleep 1.0) f
let _ = Lwt_unix.on_signal 2 (fun _ -> exit 0)
let _ = 
  print_endline "start";
  Lwt_main.at_exit (fun () -> Lwt.return(print_endline "at_exit"));
  Lwt_main.run (f ())
```

`t Lwt.t` の値を `ignore` するのまちがいである事が多い（全てそういう訳ではないが）のでその点を気を付ければ良いと思います。